# Phpstorm insert code on keyword with autocomplete

Tags: php, phpstorm

My question is if I can create my own auto complete items in Phpstorm. So when I type met and enter it will insert:

```
public function ()
{
}
```

I found a solution at [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) page, posted by [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `pubf` <kbd>tab</kbd> ?

Settings => Editor => Live templates. See more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/live-templates.html).

Comment: A better link (a tutorial rather than dry help pages): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm